# Laravel Blade-View: Handling with Api Repsonse

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

Let's say I have a simple blade view form with only one input field and a submit button. In this field you just have to write a name. After that you need to click the submit button which makes an api call.

To simplify let's say the api call is method:post and the url:'api/user'

The calling api creates a new user in the db and responses with an json:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Im a new user",
    "created_at": 20190119
}
```

As I know if I implement my blade.view like below:

```
<form method="POST" action="/api/user">
    @csrf
    <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="username"
               class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Name') }}</label>

        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input id="username" type="text"
                   class="form-control"
                   name="username" value="{{ old('username') }}" required autofocus>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row mb-0">
        <div class="col-md-8 offset-md-4">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                {{ __('Create') }}
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

My Page displays the response.
What I want is to stay at the actual view and show the response as a alert e.g. $name . ' has has been created'

Api route (routes/api.php):

```
Route::post('/user', 'UserController@createUser');
```

Route config (routes/web.php):

```
Route::get('/user' , function () {
return view('user/create-user');
});
```

Solutions that I know could work

- redirect to the same page (this means rerender the same page again and this is not really responsible - this solution leads to load the entire page again)
- return the same view in the UserController@createUser method with data (same as above and as far as I know an api call should response with a json and not with a view)

Also I could use Ajax via  e.g. JQuery. As you can see there are bunch of solutions but which ones are the best.

Can you say in that case there are best practices?

Are there good solutions that laravel brings out of the box?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are missing a few elements, or may wish to study a little more on how the various parts are put together.  Your main request isn't particularly a Laravel item:

> What I want is to stay at the actual view and show the response as a alert

The crux of this is not something Laravel 'brings out of the box', it is not really a Laravel question, but rather how do I asynchronously update my page.  For this, you might be best suited to use an ajax request followed by a javascript/jQuery alert.

I might do something like this:

```
$('#submitButton').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault(); // Want to stay on the page, not go through normal form  
        // Might be easier to make this a NON submit button - then we can use the rest below and not have to js submit()
        // Grab any extra info via data.
        var item_type = $(this).data('item-type');
        var name = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            url: "{{url('user/create/')}}",
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                item_type: item_type,
                name: name
            },
            success: function (name) {
                alert(message);
                // Or, if you want a better looking alert, you can use a library like SWAL:
               swal("Success!", "New user created with a name of: "+name, "success");
            },
            error: function () {
                swal("Error", "Unable to bring up the dialog.", "error");
            }
        });
    });
```

You'll need to handle the ajax data in your controller, and send back just the name in the controller method's return statement.

If you want to change the form above and not do this via an alert, use jQuery in the success function to make the changes (like `$("#name").text(name);` or something similar.