# Laravel 8 password.update working on postman but not in browser (302 response)

Tags: php, laravel-8

Hi I am trying to change laravel password, it is working in postman but not in browser.

Following is the code

api.php

```
Route::post('password/reset', 'App\Http\Controllers\Api\ResetPasswordController@reset')->name('password.update');
```

ResetPasswordController

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Api;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ResetsPasswords;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;


    class ResetPasswordController extends Controller
    {
        /*
        |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        | Password Reset Controller
        |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        |
        | This controller is responsible for handling password reset requests
        | and uses a simple trait to include this behavior. You're free to
        | explore this trait and override any methods you wish to tweak.
        |
        */
    
        use ResetsPasswords;
    
        protected function sendResetResponse(Request $request, $response)
        {
            return response(['message'=> trans($response)]);
    
        }
    
        protected function sendResetFailedResponse(Request $request, $response)
        {
            return response(['error'=> trans($response)], 422);
        }
    }
```

reset.blade.php

```
 <div class="reset_header">
                Reset Password
            </div>
            <form class="reset_form"  method="post" action="{{ route('password.update') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                @csrf
                <div>
                    <input type="hidden" id="token" name="token" class=""  value="{{ app('request')->input('token') }}">
                </div>
                <div>
                    <input type="text" id="email" name="email" class="" required="" placeholder="Email">
                </div>
                <div>
                    <input type="text" id="password" name="password" class="" required="" placeholder="New Password">
                </div>
                <div>
                    <input type="text" id="confirm_password" name="confirm_password" class="" required="" placeholder="Confirm Password">
                </div>
                <div>
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
                </div>
                <div>{{ app('request')->input('token') }}</div>
            </form>
```

The status code on Postman is 422 (unprocessable entity) with response as

```
{
    "error": "This password reset token is invalid."
}
```

On The browser the status code is `302 Found with blank response.`

Comment: I can write a separate controller and for the web based changing and write the whole logic manually but was thinking to be able to use the same api..

Comment: Using ajax like here seems to be working : https://stackoverflow.com/a/54268832/3904109